# How to append an empty value to NSData Array (Swift)

Tags: arrays, swift, nsdata

I have

```
var images: [NSData] = [];
```

and I need to add empty values into this array during executing of my for-loop block and then replace these empty values on NSData of the images I downloaded from the server.

**How should I append an empty value to NSData-array?**

I tried some like `... as! NSData`, or create variable `someVar: NSData?` - app crashes every time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have your array be optional NSData like so:

```
var images: [NSData?] = [];
```

That way, you can set `nil` if you want:

```
images.append(nil)
```

And check on the loop:

```
for imageData in images {
    if let data = imageData {
        // data exists
    } else {
        // data doesn't exist yet at this index
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Create an empty `Data` (`NSData` in Swift 2) instance and append it to the array

```
var images: [Data] = []
let emptyData = Data()
images.append(emptyData)
```

Answer (score 4):

Make an array of optionals `var images: [NSData?] = [];`
And add nil values when in for-loop `images.append(nil)`
After that replace with your real data if you know position in array